# Renaming operands in [

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sh

In bash, it is very often necessary to use the operands of the function `[`:

https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html

Question - is there a way to rename abbreviated and incomprehensible `-z`/`-n`/etc to normal `--is-empty`/`--is-not-empty`/etc custom names?

A CONVINCING REQUEST is not to go into philosophical discussions about whether it is necessary or not, etc., I will ignore and report such comments.

I am only interested in thoughts on the case - how to rename operands to functions `[`. Thanks for understanding!

Comment: @Jetchisel I have a question about bash programming

Comment: Dear @Avraam, this is not possible. The `test` command ( `[` and `test`) as well as its bash-internal versions (`[`) only have single-hyphen options.  It is always possible to write your own function that mimics the behaviour you want and alias it or place it in an additional PATH. However, this would become very confusing for others to understand your code.

Comment: I have downvoted, because `I will ignore and report such comments` is a threat for me and introduces fear for me to express myself clearly. Instead, consider promoting health discussions on any topic.

Comment: technically speaking you can define `[` as a function `function [ () { ...; }` so you can make it work the way you like.

Comment: The downside of creating the `[` into a function is when another program/script is depends/using `[` which does not know about the modified (long) options etc, unless of course the options that came from `[` is not removed.

Comment: The closest I can think of is to use shell variables. If you define `is_empty=z`, then you can indeed use `-$is_empty` instead of `-z`. However (just my personal opinion) I would consider this approach utmost ugly and I don't think it would pass any code review. As long as you are using it just privately for your own code, and are happy with it, go ahead and do it!

Comment: It's not possible to create custom names for `test`/`[`/`[[` operators.  You might find it useful to define utility functions like `is_empty`, `is_file`, `is_symlink`, `is_readable`, etc, and use them instead of `test`.

Comment: "*I will ignore and report such comments.*" Why, exactly, you should  **report** a civil, on-topic comment?

Answer (score 3):

> is there a way

There is always "a way". You can write a `[` bash builtin to overwrite the existing one. You can compile your own version of Bash with different `[` options. You can replace `/usr/bin/[` executable with a custom one. Etc.

> I am only interested in thoughts on the case

Do not do it. The operands are what they are and have been for many decades. Instead, learn what they are now and get used to it. Writing your own version of tools will result in maintenance burden, bugs and will confuse other programmers. Instead, write code that not only you, but anyone can understand and maintain and code that follows standardization like POSIX and existing practices.